# Find POST parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, html, parameters, http-post

I'm working on website automation by analyzing GET/POST requests in Firebug.
The issue I cannot resolve is that I can't find some particular parameter being sent in POST request.
It doesn't exist in HTML and I can't find it in *.JS files.
Where can it be?

Or give me some tips on how to find parameters in sources properly? I find Firebug very useful on this task.

UPDATE: I see this parameter in POST request. I just cannot find code in HTML sources which generate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tool you might use is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which will let you capture the data being sent to the website and analyze it.

> UPDATE: I see this parameter in POST request. I just cannot find code in HTML sources which generate it

I see. Have you tried using the debugger to step through the javascript? That might help you locate the point at which the POST is created. It's also possible that the POST is being generated by server-side generated javascript -- I've seen this as a way to get around cross-domain `httpxmlrequest` restrictions (also called ["same-origin policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). The pattern is called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), if you think this may be the culprit.

Comment: Wireshark is also a good one.  Fiddler's my personal favorite though :)

Comment: Wireshark is far more low-level, and great for non-HTTP traffic, although I actually prefer Microsoft Network Monitor over Wireshark. Fiddler is a more useful tool over either for anything that goes through a web proxy, though.

Comment: @JeffreyRasmussen: In the script tab, click in the margin next to the line number. If the button has inline javascript that calls a function, find the function definition in your scripts and set the break point there. For more info, see here: http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

POST parameters are submitted inside the request's bodys. If it's empty, then no parameters have been submitted.